# Need help with finding unbiased estimator

Tags: statistics, estimation

Suppose that $T$, the time to failure of a component is exponentially distributed. That
is, the pdf for $T$ is
$${f(x; θ) = \frac{1}
{θ}
e
^{\textbf{-}x/θ}
, 0 ≤ x < ∞}$$.
Suppose we test n components and record the failure times $T_1, . . . , T_n$.

(a) Show that $\hatθ = \overline{T} = n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} T_i$
is an unbiased estimator of $θ$.

(b) What is the variance of $\hatθ$?

(c) It can be shown that $Z = \min(T_1, . . . , T_n)$ also has an exponential distribution
with parameter $θ/n$. That is
$$g(z; θ) = \frac{1}
{θ/n}e^
{−z/(θ/n)}$$
(Do not show this). Use this to find
another unbiased estimator $\tilde{θ}$ of $θ$ and determine its variance.

For part (a): I showed $E
(\hatθ) = E(\theta)$ through rules regarding addition of expected values.

For part (b): Through independence, I showed that $var(\hatθ) =  \frac{θ^2}{n}$ (Here I assumed independence which I hope is correct. I'm also not entirely sure that I've done this question correctly).

But I'm having trouble with part (c). I know how to show something is an unbiased estimator but I'm unsure how to find an unbiased estimator. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: You are given a random variable of expectation θ/n and are asked to provide a random variable of expectation θ and have no clue?

Comment: Asking the OP to put their brain on position "On": the most serious offense that can exist.

Comment: I've edited the question. Hopefully it is no longer considered off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part (c), you can apply Maximum Likelihood Method to the only data , namely $z=\min(t_1,\cdots,t_n)$. Then you will get $\hat{\theta}=nZ$, which is unbiased.

Comment: Dunno why I didn't see this answer until now. Thanks!